# AngularJS - linking Fn is evaluated many times in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('heyo')
})

.directive('panel', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div ng-if="isAuthenticated()">Im In!</div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var uid = 3

      scope.isAuthenticated = function() {
        console.log(uid)
        return uid !== null
      }

    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <panel></panel>
</div>
```

My question is very simple and concise.
The `console.log` is evaluated 50 times on my app, while only 2 here.

What is going on?

I think it's related, if not tied, to the `$digest()` cycle, but a more illuminated answer would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngIf calls a $watch function on the provided expression, which is "isAuthenticated()" in your case.

This expression will be called on every $digest call. see: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

In the above link, please notice:

> The watchExpression is called on every call to $digest() and should
>   return the value that will be watched.

But also:

> Since $digest() reruns when it detects changes the watchExpression can execute multiple times per $digest() and should be idempotent

Here you can watch how ngClick invokes digest resulting in ngIf evaluating it's expression
http://jsfiddle.net/kihu/bbs8ajnk/2/

This line logs the digest loops:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function(){console.log("digest")}, function(){console.log('looped')});
```

Comment: indeed it gets triggered for every item "linked" to the view with `$scope`. Got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `link` function that's evaluated several times, it's `isAuthenticated` method that's checked everytime `$digest` process is running (basicaly anytime the model changes).

You can see here http://plnkr.co/edit/3mHI2wxELwdF5Th2Pjhk?p=preview that every time `$scope.y` changes it evaluates `isAuthenticated`